# Delphi FMX iOS app. How to open app notifications settings

Tags: ios, delphi

In my App, written in Delphi Rio 10.3.3, to access the app's notifications control panel, I use the following code for Android:

```
LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJSettings.JavaClass.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
LIntent.putExtra(TJSettings.JavaClass.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName)
TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
```

Is it possible to do it also for IOS devices?
Thanks in advance for any replies.
Regards: Max Justin

Comment: It doesn't open the notifications part direct, however this apparently opens the settings app: https://community.embarcadero.com/component/easydiscuss/ios-deep-linking-to-settings?Itemid=1

Comment: Thanks ! For what I need, it's an excellent solution. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution that I have adopted is the following:

```
var
  NSU: NSUrl;

NSU := StrToNSUrl(NSStrToStr(CocoaNSStringConst('/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit', 'UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString')));

if SharedApplication.canOpenURL(NSU) then
  SharedApplication.openURL(NSU);
```

I hope I have helped someone.

Comment: This doesn't work on my code..... I am running on iOS 14.8 .....

Comment: Sorry, the solution doesn't work for this version. Unfortunately it was fine for older versions. If I find any tricks, I'll let you know. Regards.